# Remove email latest news field from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a beginner and I am using wordpress with Astra and "Bestselling Author" starter template.
How can I remove the section "latest update" ?
I want to remove it with elementor but it is not working.

[image: Wordpress email template]